# Apply CSS in nth-child to nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to add styling to a nth-child to the nth-child?

I'm working a list of students(15 students) where the first 5 students their names will turn to green, then 6-10 is orange, and 11-15 is red.

its like applying CSS to range of items.

I cant find some related problem.

Hope you understand me.

Thanks.

```css
ol li:first-child{
  color: green;
}
ol li:nth-child(2), ol li:nth-child(3), ol li:nth-child(4), ol li:nth-child(5){
  color: green;
}
ol li:nth-child(6), ol li:nth-child(7), ol li:nth-child(8), ol li:nth-child(9), ol li:nth-child(10){
  color: orange;
}
ol li:nth-child(11), ol li:nth-child(12), ol li:nth-child(13), ol li:nth-child(14), ol li:nth-child(15){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>student1</li>
  <li>student2</li>
  <li>student3</li>
  <li>student4</li>
  <li>student5</li>
  <li>student6</li>
  <li>student7</li>
  <li>student8</li>
  <li>student9</li>
  <li>student10</li>
  <li>student11</li>
  <li>student12</li>
  <li>student13</li>
  <li>student14</li>
  <li>student15</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: just added the code sir

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you want?

In this first css `-n+5` selecting first five elements before `5th` element because of negetive. If you remove negetive it will select all elements with 5th elements. Therefore again added `n+11` for elements 11 to 15.

You can use `.second` css if you don't want to add css after 15th element.

```css
.first p:nth-child(-n+5) {
  color: green;
}

.first p:nth-child(n + 5) {
  color: orange;
}

.first p:nth-child(n + 11) {
  color: red;
}

.second {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.second p:nth-child(-n+5) {
  color: green;
}

.second p:nth-child(n + 6):nth-child(-n + 10) {
  color: orange;
}

.second p:nth-child(n + 11):nth-child(-n + 15) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <p>Student 1</p>
  <p>Student 2</p>
  <p>Student 3</p>
  <p>Student 4</p>
  <p>Student 5</p>
  <p>Student 6</p>
  <p>Student 7</p>
  <p>Student 8</p>
  <p>Student 9</p>
  <p>Student 10</p>
  <p>Student 11</p>
  <p>Student 12</p>
  <p>Student 13</p>
  <p>Student 14</p>
  <p>Student 15</p>
</div>

<div class="second">
  <p>Student 1</p>
  <p>Student 2</p>
  <p>Student 3</p>
  <p>Student 4</p>
  <p>Student 5</p>
  <p>Student 6</p>
  <p>Student 7</p>
  <p>Student 8</p>
  <p>Student 9</p>
  <p>Student 10</p>
  <p>Student 11</p>
  <p>Student 12</p>
  <p>Student 13</p>
  <p>Student 14</p>
  <p>Student 15</p>
  <p>Student 16</p>
  <p>Student 17</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You could provide an explanation along with your code :)

Comment: Yes..sure..let me explain

Comment: this works until you can override the style. without last selector all of your children would be orange

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS child range to achieve your solution.

Your style should be as below

```css
li:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+8) {
  background: #298EB2;
}

li {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Child Ranges</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><span></span></li>
    <li><span></span></li>
    <li><span></span></li>
    <li><span></span></li>
    <li><span></span></li>
    <li><span></span></li>
    <li><span></span></li>
    <li><span></span></li>
    <li><span></span></li>
    <li><span></span></li>
    <li><span></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nutboltu/dm428y37/3/)

If you want to learn more about nth-child, you can visit this site http://nthmaster.com/

Answer (score 3):

Have a loot this code. According to your requirements.

```css
ul li{
 margin-bottom: 2px;
}
ul li:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+5) {
  background: #2e8209;
}
ul li:nth-child(n+6):nth-child(-n+10) {
  background: #eb7436;
}
ul li:nth-child(n+11):nth-child(-n+15) {
  background: #b10a0a;
}
```

```html
<ul>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
            <li>Child 3</li>
            <li>Child 4</li>
            <li>Child 5</li>
            <li>Child 6</li>
            <li>Child 7</li>
            <li>Child 8</li>
            <li>Child 9</li>
            <li>Child 10</li>
            <li>Child 11</li>
            <li>Child 12</li>
            <li>Child 13</li>
            <li>Child 14</li>
            <li>Child 15</li>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

p:not(:nth-child(n+7)) {
    color: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>One</p>
<p>Two</p>
<p>Three</p>
<p>Four</p>
<p>Five</p>
<p>Six</p>
<p>Seven</p>
<p>Eight</p>

</body>
</html>
```

below code will give green color only for first five rows ,
Assumeing p tag is ur class ,

```
p:not(:nth-child(n+7)) {
color: green;
```

}